# My wordpress site not compatible in IE11

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-11, compatibility

My wordpress template doesn’t compatible in IE11 But working fine in chrome,safari,Firefox. The page just cannot appear and the pre-loader icon keep spinning.

I try to check the debug console and found the jquery got some error.

http://www.grittnco.com/wp-content/themes/melissa/assets/js/super-guacamole.min.js?ver=1.0.0

The supper-guacamole.min.js return error from command
e.constructor.name.toLowerCase()

Unable to get property ‘tolowecase’ of undefined or null reference.

Do anybody face the wordpress theme compatibility problem in IE11?

The Wordpress theme is downloaded from template monster theme name Melissa. My wordpress version 4.92.

Just some month ago it still working fine at IE but just recent Therese is feedback not workin anymore.

https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/52153.html

Comment: seems issue with this js. just comment this js and check. http://www.grittnco.com/wp-content/themes/melissa/assets/js/super-guacamole.min.js?ver=1.0.0

Comment: This question is extremely vague.  When you say that site isn't working, what do you mean?  Is there a specific functionality that isn't working?  Is the site not loading at all?  Where is the code you're having issues with?  When/if your problem is fixed then there is no value left to users who come across this question in the future.

Comment: Hi Justin , sorry about that i not mean to asking question vague as I am download a template building my own website, so there are very limited knowledge about the template so I not sure which function goes wrong as the site are working fine at other browser but not at IE. I guess it is some compability problem on Java but have no crew where it is.

Comment: Hello George , I try to comment out the function you mentioned but the page goes wrong on all the browser and the preloader just keep spinning without disappear.

Comment: I try not to be too harsh on new users, but unfortunately this question just has no details that we can work on. It's akin to saying "my car doesn't work can some one tell me why?" There are tens of (if not hundreds of thousands of) WordPress themes. You didn't specify which theme, you haven't specified which WordPress version. Please add detail.

Comment: Hi Rick , I have edited my post with more info. Sorry about that

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Disable that plugin and see if the site works. To be honest that sounds like kind of a crappy plugin anyway. Hide menu items instead of writing proper CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Most websites no matter from where they are, they look diferent or look bad in IE so dont waste your time with IE

Comment: IE11 still has significant usage, telling people randomly to just ignore a certain percentage of their possible user base is a horrible answer.